# Document's IDs and order by in a query throws an error (Firestore)

Tags: ios, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As I was trying to get certain documents from Firestore,

I was getting the error:

> inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: __name__ and field

while indexing my Firestore database with this query:

```
db.collection("collection").whereField(.documentID(), in: array).order(by: "field")
```

this query works fine without the order by (which is ordering an int).

The issue seems to be that using a document id and an order by statement in a query throws an error.

Are there any work arounds or solutions to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that if a query specifies inequality filters on a property and sort orders on other properties, the property used in the inequality filters must be ordered before the other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore can't execute this query because the "in" filter uses document ID (internally known as "__name__"), which is different than your sort order.

The easiest workaround is to simply sort the documents in your app code.  Since an "in" query can only return 10 documents maximum, this should pose no real problems at all on modern hardware.